# What does the "RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task ... while another task ... is being executed" mean in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-asyncio, qasync

I'm trying to troubleshoot this error in a fairly complex Python 3.9 project with PyQt 5.15 and `qasync` (error sanitized for privacy):

```
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-11911' coro=<*** running at ***:454> cb=[asyncSlot.<locals>._error_handler() at /mnt/data/opt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qasync/__init__.py:778, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f64291790>()]> while another task <Task pending name='Task-11910' coro=<*** running at ***.py:1038> cb=[asyncSlot.<locals>._error_handler() at /mnt/data/opt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qasync/__init__.py:778]> is being executed.
```

I'm not sure I understand the error, and a quick search online only returns links to specific packages, not an explanation of the error itself. What does the error mean in practice?

Comment: It would help us greatly if you could [edit] this question to include the code that caused this error.

Comment: Sorry but your question lacks the fundamental context required to understand the issue. While the error may be *generically* understood, it's impossible to get its cause without any relevant code. Please provide a valid [mre], otherwise you'll only get wild guesses, and that's not the purpose of StackOverflow.